# Invalid URI scheme in origin coming from firebase when on my android phone

Tags: android, firebase

When I use the search bar on my android phone to visit my website, I get the error 'Invalid URI scheme in origin'.  It's coming from firebase.  Specifically, the line, from the obfuscated code:

```
if("http"!==a&&"https"!==a&&"chrome-extension"!==a&&"file"!==a)
    throw Error("Invalid URI scheme in origin");
```

a is 'android-app'. This seems like an error.

The site works fine when I visit from the Chrome browser on my phone.

The error is thrown when loading the firebase module, included via

`var Firebase = require('firebase')`

Comment: show your piece of code